# How to access static methods?

Tags: java, jna

Using Java and the JNA library, I want to access static methods found within a commercial DLL file (C#).

Unfortunately Java 7 does not allow static methods within an interface, and although Java 8 will amend this the latest beta release appears indifferent.

Suggests/corrections are welcome (I am new to JNA and am avoiding JNI), and I have used Javonet to confirm the method signature.

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class INeedHelp {
   public interface MyInterface extends Library {
       public static boolean isDisconnected(); //Mirror of C# method signature, but wont work
       public boolean isDisconnected(); //best fit, but throws exception "Error looking up function 'isDisconnected': The specified procedure could not be found."
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       MyInterface anInstance = (MyInterface) Native.loadLibrary("theDLL", MyInterface.class);
       anInstance.isDisconnected();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [Direct Mapping](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/DirectMapping.md), something like;

```
import com.sun.jna.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static native boolean isDisconnected();

    static {
        Native.register("theDLL");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass.isDisconnected();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it is not related to the question, but could you explain what does `static` in `static {
        Native.register("theDLL");
    }` do?

Comment: @Jari It's a [static initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) and it will be run by the JVM when first initializing the class type. In other words, it will always have been run by the JVM before any code can call or use the class.

Comment: Oh, it is like a static constructor? Awesome

Comment: @Jari Yes, the only real difference being that there can usually be only one static constructor per class in languages that support it, while there can be any number of static initializers in a Java class :)